# variable cumulative target point without new row OR without VBA

Tags: excel

What I need to do is (please refer to the image below):

1. red numbers in C column should be calculated by excel. I wrote the
   values that must be calculated after the proper formula is applied.
2. Each red number in C column gives the 1st point that the total of the values between D & I columns are >= related confidence level. For example:

C2 value is 2 because  `D2+E2+F2>=0,85`. Since F2 is the 1st point to satisfy this requirement, C2 value is 2 (value of F1)

another example; C3 is 0 since immediately `D3>=B3` already.

It won't be a proper solution to use *only* `IF()` function (that is what I can do but not proper) because this image is a simplified version of my real case. In my real case columns that are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are extended until 60.

Is there any solution to this case

1. without VBA
2. without creating new rows for calculating cumulative values (*there are also tons of reference rows so new rows will create fill-down inefficiencies*)

regards

[image]

Comment: You can add new *columns* to the right of your existing columns, and use those for cumulative values: then there's no problem with fill-down.

Comment: absolutely right Tim, I ashamed for not seeing this solution, I think I got very tired. Pls convert your comment to an answer, let me accept. Do you think that (if your solution was inapplicable) what I required could be done with usual functions?

Comment: Formulas aren't my strength: I'm sure someone else here would be able to figure out a direct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to add new columns to the right of your existing columns, and use those for cumulative values: then there's no problem with fill-down.